# How to define dynamic boundaries for a dragable object in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Am having two controls on my video player to choose start and end points, please refer attached image

[image]
Name of these contorls is respectively **inpoint_mc** and **scrub_outpoint_mc**, i added Listener functions to drag itself for both controls

```
this.controls_mc.inpoint_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, this.startScrubbingIN);
            this.controls_mc.scrub_outpoint_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, this.startScrubbingOUT);

private function startScrubbingIN(_arg1:MouseEvent){
            trace("scrubBarIsMovingIN");
            this.cueCard.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, this.stopScrubbingIN);
            this.cueCard.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, this.scrubBarIsMovingIN);
            this.scrubbing = true;
            var _local2:Rectangle = new Rectangle(this.controls_mc.progressBar_mc.x, this.controls_mc.inpoint_mc.y, this.controls_mc.progressBar_mc.width, 0);
            this.controls_mc.inpoint_mc.startDrag(false, _local2);

        }

        private function startScrubbingOUT(_arg1:MouseEvent){
            this.cueCard.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, this.stopScrubbingOUT);
            this.cueCard.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, this.scrubBarIsMovingOUT);
            this.scrubbing = true;
            var _local2:Rectangle = new Rectangle(this.controls_mc.progressBar_mc.x, this.controls_mc.scrub_outpoint_mc.y, this.controls_mc.progressBar_mc.width, 0);
            this.controls_mc.scrub_outpoint_mc.startDrag(false, _local2);

        }
```

My Aim is, i don't want they both go beyond each other, meant **inpoint_mc** is only dragable until it reaches **scrub_outpoint_mc**, and **scrub_outpoint_mc** is only dragable until it reaches **inpoint_mc**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to calculate the dragging rectangle based on the position of the other scrub point. Your rectangle now contains the area under `progressBar_mc`, now you have to trim it according to position of either `inpoint_mc` or `scrub_outpoint_mc`. To do that, you need to alter the `x` and `width` of the rectangles used to limit `startDrag()`.

```
    private function startScrubbingIN(_arg1:MouseEvent){
        trace("scrubBarIsMovingIN");
        this.cueCard.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, this.stopScrubbingIN);
        this.cueCard.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, this.scrubBarIsMovingIN);
        this.scrubbing = true;
        var _local2:Rectangle = new Rectangle(this.controls_mc.progressBar_mc.x, this.controls_mc.inpoint_mc.y, 
            this.controls_mc.scrub_outpoint_mc.x-this.controls_mc.progressBar_mc.x, 0);
        // now we're limiting in point to current position of out point
        this.controls_mc.inpoint_mc.startDrag(false, _local2);

    }

    private function startScrubbingOUT(_arg1:MouseEvent){
        this.cueCard.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, this.stopScrubbingOUT);
        this.cueCard.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, this.scrubBarIsMovingOUT);
        this.scrubbing = true;
        var _local2:Rectangle = new Rectangle(this.controls_mc.inpoint_mc.x, this.controls_mc.scrub_outpoint_mc.y, 
            this.controls_mc.progressBar_mc.width+this.controls_mc.progressBar_mc.x-this.controls_mc.inpoint_mc.x, 0);
        // the same for out, but the width of the rectangle is calculated to include x offset
        this.controls_mc.scrub_outpoint_mc.startDrag(false, _local2);

    }
```

Comment: Vesper , is it possible to fill the Rectangle with any color ?

Comment: Well, this is worthy of another question with enough details on where do you want to place a colored rectangle, etc. In short, yes, but implementation will vary.

Comment: Absolutely on the same rectangle we created using the above codes, check the question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32437018/how-to-fill-a-rectangle-with-any-color-in-as3?noredirect=1#comment52739753_32437018

Comment: Actually my aim is about to highlight the area between `inpoint_mc` and `scrub_outpoint_mc`

Comment: any guess on my new question ?