# How to fill a rectangle with any color in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Am drawing a rectangle to move my scrubBar in a progressbar, it's working fine, now i need to fill the rectangle with some colors ?

```
 private function startScrubbingOUT(_arg1:MouseEvent){
            this.cueCard.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, this.stopScrubbingOUT);
            this.cueCard.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, this.scrubBarIsMovingOUT);
            this.scrubbing = true;
            var _local2:Rectangle = new Rectangle(this.controls_mc.progressBar_mc.x, this.controls_mc.scrub_outpoint_mc.y, this.controls_mc.progressBar_mc.width, 0);
            this.controls_mc.scrub_outpoint_mc.startDrag(false, _local2);

        }
```

i had reffered Rectangle class here [Rectangle Class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Rectangle.html)

but i can't find any attribute to fill the Rectangle, help to figureout this

Comment: A `Rectangle` in flash is simple a geometric figure, not a DisplayObject. If you want to draw a Rectangle, look into [drawing shapes with AS3](http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/792/1/Drawing-Shapes-with-AS3/Page1.html)

Comment: `_arg1`, `_local2` are you sure this is _your_ code and not the output of a decompiler? Writing your own code from scratch might provide a better learning experience than modifying an existing code base that stems from a decompiler.

Comment: @null it's not the code from decompiler, it's my colleague code, he left now so am working on this

Comment: @DodgerThud , Square only having x and y, how i could draw rectangle ?

Comment: No, a square does not only have x and y, it also has a width and a height. Squares are rectangles where the height and width is the same.

Comment: The recommendation still holds, make yourself familiar with the display list and the related classes, DisplayObject, DispalyObjectContainer, Sprite, Shape, Graphics ...